# C++ const-cast a reference

Tags: c++, const-cast

Is this correct? 
It compiles with my compiler but I've been told it doesn't with an AIX one.

```
typedef std::vector<Entry>::iterator Iterator;
typedef std::vector<Entry>::const_iterator ConstIterator;

bool funct(ConstIterator& iter) const;
inline bool funct(Iterator& iter){return funct(const_cast<ConstIterator&>(iter));}
```

What should I do to let my code compile on the AIX platform? 
(Beside reimplement the non const version with Ctrl-C Ctrl-V).

Comment: You don't need the non-const version. The compiler will call the const version for non-const objects as well as const objects. Don't know about compilers on AIX, but unless you've got code that shows that there is a problem it's really not possible to diagnose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const_cast` is used to remove const-ness of a variable. That is if you have `const A& a` you can write `A& b = const_cast<A&>(a)`. Now you will be able to modify `b` or call non-const methods on it.

In this case you construct a `const_iterator` from a regular `iterator` and this is always possible even without using a `const_cast`. Keep in mind these are two different types and simply `const_iterator` happened to be constructable from `iterator` C++ const-ness does not have much to do in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`iterator` and `const_iterator` are (in general) different types, so you can't cast references. However, `iterator` is convertible to `const_iterator`, so you could do

```
return funct(static_cast<ConstIterator>(iter));
```

or, more safely since it only allows explicit conversions:

```
ConstIterator citer = iter;
return funct(citer);
```